# filter_queryset with boolean field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-queryset

I have the following view:

```py
class MessagesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing the messages
    associated with the user.
    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [MessageFields.MARK_READ]

    def get_user(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(sent_to=self.get_user())

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(sender=self.get_user())

    @action(detail=True, )
    def unread_messages(self, request, pk):
        """
        Return all of the user's unread messages.
        """
        data = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serialized_data = MessageSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

in `unread_messages` I want to return only the object that has `mark_read = True` (It's a boolean field).
right now it returns all objects because there's no restriction in the method about being True or False.

So how can I set some sort of a flag in the method?

Comment: Can you add the code of your filter_backends?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `mark_read=False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter it with `mark_read` is (likely) `False`:

```
class MessagesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing the messages
    associated with the user.
    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [MessageFields.MARK_READ]

    def get_user(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(sent_to=self.get_user(), mark_read=False)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(sender=self.get_user())

    @action(detail=True, )
    def unread_messages(self, request, pk):
        """
        Return all of the user's unread messages.
        """
        data = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serialized_data = MessageSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

or you can filter these only in the `unread_messages` with:

```
class MessagesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing the messages
    associated with the user.
    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [MessageFields.MARK_READ]

    def get_user(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(sent_to=self.get_user())

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(sender=self.get_user())

    @action(detail=True, )
    def unread_messages(self, request, pk):
        """
        Return all of the user's unread messages.
        """
        data = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).filter(mark_read=False)
        serialized_data = MessageSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```